# The result of two products of negligible functions

Tags: real-analysis, functions, discrete-mathematics, polynomials

According to the definitions of negligible functions, the product of a negligible function and a positive polynomial results in a negligible function.

With this in mind, I was also wondering whether the product of two negligible functions would result in a new negligible function? That is the product of a(n).b(n) where a and b are negligible functions, now results in another negligible function?

Comment: The answer depends on the definition of *negligible*.

Comment: Presumably [this definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negligible_function).

Comment: There has been a rash of questions on negligible functions, all with users failing to include or link to a definition of *negligible*.

Answer (score 0):

From the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negligible_function), if $f$ is negligible and $|g(n)| \le |f(n)|$ for sufficiently large $n$, then $g$ is negligible.  Now taking $p(n)=1$, if $a$ is negligible then $|a(n)| \le 1$ for sufficiently large $n$.  Therefore $|a(n) b(n)| \le |b(n)|$ for such $n$, and that implies that $a(n) b(n)$ is negligible.